# Why does physisorption pass into chemisorption on increasing temperature

Tags: surface-chemistry

I have been told, that on increasing temperature, physisorption passes into chemisorption (with greater Activation Energy, generally). But why does that happen?

Shouldn’t the increment in Temperature decrease the bond strength of attractive forces like van der Waal’s, instead of resulting into the formation of chemical bonds?

Comment: Do you have a reference?

Comment: Increasing temperature does not affect the potential energy or forces, but makes it more likely that higher energy levels will be populated. So if there is a small physisorption well with a big energy barrier to a v. deep chemisorption, well heating will allow the chemisorption well to become populated.